# Pandas barplot stack entries counts sum lower than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I hava a pandas dataframe like this one:

```
    name  | count
   ---------------
   apple      784
   pen        325
   car          4
   cat       1345
   dog          8
 banana         1
```

Now I want to create a barplot in which all the entries which contribute for lower than the 5% of the total 'count' are grouped together in a new entry like 'OTHERS'

```
    name  | count
   ---------------
   apple      784
   pen        325
   cat       1345
  others       13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try mapping the small `name` into `other` and plot:

```
mask = df['count']/df['count'].sum() < 0.05
categories = np.where(mask, 'other', df['name'])

df.groupby(categories)['count'].sum().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

You can also sort the sum series before plot:

```
(df.groupby(categories)['count'].sum()
   .sort_values(ascending=False).plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]